# How to insert custom button in shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make a button as shown in the attached figure, which in this case is a bigger button than the ones used by the shiny code, which when clicked goes to a certain page. In the code below if you click on `Download` it goes to a certain page, in this case, then I would like it to be a button. If possible, leave the button centered.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                    title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                    
                    tabPanel("",
                             div(
                               style =
                                 "height: 80px;  background-color: #2C3E50; width: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;",
                               
                               div(
                                 style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
                                 
                                 h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
                                    style="text-align:center; color: white;"),
                                 hr(),
                                 h4(HTML("Accumsan nostra eu sodales etiam interdum lacus nullam pretium congue, dolor phasellus tincidunt metus auctor scelerisque."),
                                    
                                    style="text-align: justify"),
                                 br(),
                                 h4(HTML("The database spreadsheet can be downloaded from the following link: "),
                                    uiOutput("tab"),
                                                                            style="text-align: justify"),
                                 
                                 br(),
                                tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")))))





server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  url <- a("Download", href="https://google.com")
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tags$span("",style = "font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;"), url)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output**

[image]

Example of button

[image]

Comment: The page usually crashes for me, but on the left hand side, under "bttn", you can see the different buttons available in the ```shinyWidgets``` package which I'm fond of: http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 div(
                                     style =
                                         "height: 80px;  background-color: #2C3E50; width: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;",
                                     
                                     div(
                                         style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
                                         
                                         h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
                                            style="text-align:center; color: white;"),
                                         hr(),
                                         h4(HTML("Accumsan nostra eu sodales etiam interdum lacus nullam pretium congue, dolor phasellus tincidunt metus auctor scelerisque."),
                                            
                                            style="text-align: justify"),
                                         br(),
                                         h4(HTML("The database spreadsheet can be downloaded from the following link: "),
                                            uiOutput("tab"),
                                            style="text-align: justify"),
                                         
                                         br(),
                                         tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")))))





server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    url <- a("Download", href="https://google.com", class = "my-btn")
    
    output$tab <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            url,
            tags$style(HTML(
                '
                .my-btn {
                    display: block;
                    text-align: center;
                    background: rgb(241 119 65 / 75%);;
                    width: 500px;
                    color: white;
                    transform: translateX(-50%);
                    left: 50%;
                    font-size: 3rem;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                    position: relative;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                }
                .my-btn:hover {
                    text-decoration: unset;
                    color: white;
                }
                '
            ))
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]